# Kill the worker threads after 'done' event in threads module nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to kill the worker threads after the 'done' event is fired in Threads module of Nodejs. How do I achieve this?

```
const Threads = require('threads');
const Pool = Threads.Pool; 
const workerPool = new Pool();

module.exports = class JobManager {
    static bufferedJob(pathToScript, params, callback){
        workerPool
        .run(pathToScript)
        .send(params)
        .on('done', (result, input) => {
            console.log(`Worker Job done: ${pathToScript} `);
            callback(null, result);
        })        
        .on('error', (job, error) => {
            console.log(`Error in executing Worker Job: ${pathToScript}`);
            callback(job || error);
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

port.close()
Added in: v10.5.0
Disables further sending of messages on either side of the connection. This method can be called when no further communication will happen over this MessagePort.

The 'close' event will be emitted on both MessagePort instances that are part of the channel.

Comment: port2.on('close', () => console.log('closed!'));